# C structure definition translated to Python

Tags: python, c#, c, ctypes

I have a C/C# library which contains a function `functionName(int index, DataTypeDef data[], int count);`.

definition of DataTypeDef:

```
 struct DataTypeDef
    {
        public int id;                   
        public float par1;                   
        public int par2;                     

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 10)]
        public float[] result;                  

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 20)]
        public float[] result2;                

        public Int64 par3;                       
        public Int32 par4;                          
    };
```

The question is how to properly translate this part to Python using ctypes and execute the function.
My attempt to define the structure as follows:

```
import ctypes as c

class DataTypeDef(c.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("id",c.c_int),
        ("par1",c.c_float),
        ("par2",c.c_int),
        ("result",c.c_float*10),
        ("result2",c.c_float*20), 
        ("par3",c.c_long),
        ("par4",c.c_long),
        ]
```

was not successful; when the function is being executed:

```
r_index = (c.c_int)(1)
r_data = (DataTypeDef)() 
r_count = (c.c_int)(1)
functionName(r_index,r_data,r_count)
```

the python kernel just dies.
other functions where structures are not used are executed normally

Comment: @Fildor the original library is written in c# so the definition is copied from there.

Comment: @Fildor I edited the question, it is about integration of C/C# libraries to python using ctypes. I think from this point of view the tags (and their order) were correct.

Comment: Yep, I see it now. It's clearer now. I'll revert the edit of tags.

Answer (score 0):

Some types in your class definition are incorrect.  The last two parameters don't match.  `c_long` might be work for one of them, but not both.

```py
class DataTypeDef(c.Structure):
    _fields_ = (("id",c.c_int),
                ("par1",c.c_float), 
                ("par2",c.c_int),
                ("result",c.c_float*10),
                ("result2",c.c_float*20), 
                ("par3",c.c.c_int64),      # 8-byte size
                ("par4",c.c_int32))        # 4-byte size
```

You should also check for padding declarations such as `#pragma pack(push,1)` or similar in the C structure definition.  You can define `_pack_ = 1` if needed to remove padding.  for example the above structure is 152 bytes normally (4 bytes padding added after both `result2` and `par4`) and 144 bytes with 1-byte packing.  The size of the original, incorrect structure is 140 bytes, which is too small with or without packing and is likely the cause of Python crashing due to overrun of the structure.

It also helps to `printf("%zu\n", sizeof(DatatypeDef));` in C and `print(ctypes.sizeof(DataTypeDef))` in Python to make sure they agree.  Differences can indicate a structure or padding error.

Comment: Dear @mark-tolonen, thank you for the reply. I have tried with the int32 and int64 (also before the question). It does not change the situation, the python kernel dies. I thought it should be something to do with that `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 10)]
        
public float[] result; ` 

because I am not sure that these two variables result/result2 (actually they are arrays) are defined correctly.
I have checked the size of the python structure, to compare I need to get my hands on the C version.